# How to set TextBlock properties programmatically using C++/WinRT + WinUI 3

Tags: c++, c++-winrt, winui-3

I've been hiding under the MFC rock for many years so I can stick to standard C++ but still write Windows Desktop apps.  With C++/WinRT and WinUI 3.0, it appears that I may finally have an opportunity to modernize my code.  The problem is that I know nothing about XAML or the Windows API.  To fix this problem, I'm trying to work my way through Petzold's "Programming Windows, 6th ed.", replacing the C# code with C++/WinRT.  When all I have to do is write XAML, all is copacetic.  However, when I get to p. 24, I'm supposed to adjust TextBlock properties in code.  Here's the C#:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "Hello, Windows 8!";
tb.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
tb.FontSize = 96;
tb.FontStyle = FontStyle.Italic;
...
```

and here's my attempt at a replacement:

```
TextBlock tb;
tb.Text(L"Hello, Windows 8!");
tb.FontFamily(FontFamily(L"Times New Roman"));
tb.FontSize(96);
tb.FontStyle(FontStyle::Italic);
...
```

All goes well until the last line.  "FontStyle::Italic" is not recognized.  I have similar issues with the enums for Color and HorizontalAlignment.  What is the correct way to access these enums?  Have I forgotten an include or a "using"?  Here's what I currently have:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Composition.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Text.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Interop.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.h>
```

and

```
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Text;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media;
```

I hope there's a short answer to my long question.

Comment: [FontStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.fontstyle) is documented to be an `enum` (as opposed to an `enum class`). In that case use `Italic` in place of `FontStyle::Italic`.

Comment: Not so. The docs may need to be adjusted, but C++/WinRT generates all enums as scoped enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure, you'd need to post a little more detail (like what error message you're getting). But I'll take a guess that perhaps your code is missing a namespace qualifier. I'm just going off the UWP Windows namespace types, not the WinUI Microsoft namespace, but this code builds for me:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Text.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>

void f()
{
    winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock tb;
    tb.Text(L"Hello");
    tb.FontFamily(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily(L"Times New Roman"));
    tb.FontSize(96);
    tb.FontStyle(winrt::Windows::UI::Text::FontStyle::Italic);
    tb.SelectionHighlightColor(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush(winrt::Windows::UI::Colors::Red()));
    tb.HorizontalAlignment(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::HorizontalAlignment::Center);
}
```

As does this:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Text.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Text;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;

void f()
{
    TextBlock tb;
    tb.Text(L"Hello");
    tb.FontFamily(FontFamily(L"Times New Roman"));
    tb.FontSize(96);
    tb.FontStyle(FontStyle::Italic);
    tb.SelectionHighlightColor(SolidColorBrush(Colors::Red()));
    tb.HorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment::Center);
}
```

Comment: Aha!  Nailed it.  It appears that the problem was that I was using the winrt::Microsoft includes and namespaces rather than winrt::Windows.  The features I need are not yet implemented in the Microsoft namespace - just part of the prerelease caveats.  Now I just need to figure out what changed in contentGrid().Children.Append() and I'm good to go.

Comment: Ryan, Thanks for the examples that gave me the insight I needed.  BTW, I figured out the problem with contentGrid().Children.Append(): the XAML is getting the Grid from the Microsoft namespace, and the code is getting it from the Windows namespace.  I guess I'll just wait for the required update to the Microsoft namespace code.

Comment: I revisited this code recently and found that the problem was that in the XAML I was using Name="" rather than x:Name="".  It may not make a difference in C#, but it sure does in C++/WinRT